# Use Regular Expressions to find unorderedlist tags embedded in paragraph tags

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to find `<ul>` tags within `<p>` tags.  This would be an example of text that matches what I am looking for:

```
blah
<p style="font-size: 10pt;">blah</p>
<p style="font-size: 10pt;"><ul><li>blah</li></ul></p>
blah
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Maybe I just think in simpler terms than all of the people in that lengthy post.  All I want to do is find out if a string contains "<ul>" between  "<p" and "</p".This really doesn't have anything to do with HTML.  It's a regex question where I want to find string 1, then string 2 BEFORE string 3.  I don't know how to do that, but I'm sure regex can do it.

Comment: ``<p>Here's a paragraph.</p><ul>Here's a list.</ul><p>Here's another paragraph.</p>``  -- here, there is a ``<ul>`` between a ``<p>`` and a ``</p>``.  A regex can't detect that the first ``<p>`` is closed before the ``<ul>`` is opened.

Comment: And yes, you could make an EXTREMELY complex regex to check for the existence of a ``<p>`` followed by a ``<ul>`` before you see a ``</p>``, but you can't tell if it's a *matching* ``</p>``.  This would fail, for example:  ``<p><p>Inner p.</p><ul>List inside a paragraph.</ul></p>``  -- the regex would say the list is not inside a ``<p>`` when in fact it is.  Seriously, there is no way to correctly parse HTML with regex, use an HTML parser.

Comment: I'm looking for one VERY SPECIFIC

Answer (score 0):

Although I think that it's really better to use some HTML/XML parser to do this, you can try to use negative lookahead in regex, so in your case you could use

```
(<p[^>]*>(?:(?!</p>).)*)(<ul[^>]*>.*</ul>)
```

But this only works if there is only one `<ul>` in-between the `<p></p>`, if there are more the regex would become a wa-a-ay more complex, and in some terms there'd be a need to use a function as a replace.

Comment: kizu - thank you so much.  That works perfectly.  I'm looking for something very specific, not trying to parse HTML in general.